# Apache_request_headers не работает

Tags: php, apache

Нужно принять и разобрать хэш киви из заголовка

Делаю так

```
$head = apache_request_headers();
$hash = $head['X-Api-Signature'];
```

Заношу хэш в бд для просмотра, он пустой. Хотя киви заголовок отправляет.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_API_SIGNATURE']` должен содержать необходимое.

Comment: Спасибо, а поподробнее?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, подробнее что?

Comment: Отображает пустоту.